# NullPointerException with self-implemented OnClickListener

Tags: android

Sorry, but it seems like I'm just all over the place with having various OnClickListener stuff not working for the past few days...

I have a ListView of fixed various variables/data (contacts) that I'm displaying, and for each ListView item, I'm using a separate XML file (`contacts_item`) to format/display this data. Each item in the ListView is either a phone contact or an email contact. I'm trying to make it so that when one of these contacts is click, it'll start a phone call or bring up the new email. (Focusing on the calling aspect for now, but what does that matter?)

The snippet of the code from the main activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contacts_layout);

    // Show "back" button
    aboutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aboutButton);
    aboutButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Contacts.this.finish();
        }
    });

ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactItem);
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
// loop through 8 times for each contact entry
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> entry = new HashMap<String, String>();
        entry.put("title", title[i]);
        entry.put("name", name[i]);
        entry.put("label", label[i]); // Call, mail, etc.
        entry.put("info", info[i]); // The actual phone number or email

        // Check the label field of each entry
        if (label[i].equals("Call")) {
            TextLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactLabel); // contactLabel is from the separate XML file I mentioned
            Log.v("textlabel", "textlabel: " + R.id.contactLabel);

            // Crashes here              
            //TextLabel.setOnClickListener(new ContactOCL(info[i]));
        }

        // Let's see if all of this is printing out right
        Log.v("title", "Title: " + title[i]);
        Log.v("name", "Name: " + name[i]);
        Log.v("label", "Label: " + label[i]);
        Log.v("info", "Info: " + info[i]);

        items.add(entry);
}

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Contacts.this, items, R.layout.contacts_item, new String[] {"title", "name", "label", "info"},
            new int[] {R.id.contactTitle, R.id.contactName, R.id.contactLabel, R.id.contactInfo});

    // Create an inflater to use another xml layout (the Facebook/Twitter/Instagram buttons)
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_footer, null);

    // Define their clicks
    facebookButton = (ImageButton) footerView.findViewById(R.id.facebookButton);
    twitterButton = (ImageButton) footerView.findViewById(R.id.twitterButton);
    instagramButton = (ImageButton) footerView.findViewById(R.id.instagramButton);

    facebookButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Open up the Facebook page when clicked
            facebookPage = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            facebookPage.setData(Uri.parse(facebookURL));
            startActivity(facebookPage);
        }
    });

    twitterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Open up the Twitter page when clicked
            twitterPage = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            twitterPage.setData(Uri.parse(twitterURL));
            startActivity(twitterPage);
        }
    });

    instagramButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Open up the Instagram page when clicked
            instagramPage = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            instagramPage.setData(Uri.parse(instagramURL));
            startActivity(instagramPage);
        }
    });

    // Add the footer to the listview, then set adapter
    // MUST BE CALLED IN THIS ORDER!
    listview.addFooterView(footerView);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

ContactOCL:

```
public class ContactOCL extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    String contactInfo;
    public ContactOCL(String contactInfo) {
        this.contactInfo = contactInfo;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + contactInfo));
            v.getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
            Log.e("Calling a Phone Number", "Call failed", activityException);
        }
    }

}
```

And here's the stack trace:

```
02-27 16:29:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1025): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 16:29:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1025): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.radio.app/org.radio.app.Contacts}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 16:29:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
02-27 16:29:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
02-27 16:29:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-27 16:29:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
02-27 16:29:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 16:29:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-27 16:29:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-27 16:29:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 16:29:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-27 16:29:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-27 16:29:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-27 16:29:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 16:29:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1025): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 16:29:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at org.radio.app.Contacts.onCreate(Contacts.java:78)
02-27 16:29:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
02-27 16:29:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
02-27 16:29:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
```

textlabel is also printing out a few times, all of which are the same number/ID...I'm assuming that's a bad sign and NOT what I want. So I'm not really sure if it's my implementation that's causing this to crash, or...

Comment: That's the line that I commented below `// Crashes here ` in the main activity. I have no idea why it's null.

Comment: Post your whole `onCreate()` of `Contacts`. I would suspect it is due to you trying to call a `TextView` from the wrong xml. And why are you using separate xml files for each list item? That sounds like a recipe for disaster to me

Comment: Edited/updated. The XML is just for formatting/styling purposes. I wanted each item to have four (or five, can't remember) fields/variables displayed in each ListView, with different text colors and whatnot.

Comment: Is `contactLabel` the `id` of a `TextView` in `contacts_layout`?

Comment: debugg it and step into that line and tell us what is null that is not supposed to be.

Comment: TextLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactLabel); Is TextLabel supposed to be contactLabel?

Comment: @codeMagic `contactLabel` is the ID in `contacts_item`, actually. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: TextLabel is just a TextView variable...if I'm understanding what you're asking.

Comment: If TextLabel is inside listview then try this TextLabel = (TextView) listview.findViewById(R.id.contactLabel);

Comment: Where do you inflate the `contacts_item` layout?

Comment: It still crashes, unfortunately. :(

Comment: @codeMagic `contacts_item` isn't inflated, only the footer (`contacts_footer`).

Comment: you should post your xml

Comment: Then that's your problem. If you set a breakpoint at that line you should see that the `TextView` is null. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a `View` such as a `TextView` or `Button` from a `Layout` that hasn't been inflated using `setContentView()` or a `layoutInflater`. This seems to be your problem unless I missed where you did that. Put the `Views` in the `Layout` that you want to use and then you can change the attributes programaticaly if you need to for further formatting

Comment: shouldn't the `setContentView(R.layout.contacts_layout);` inflate all views in the `contacts_layout`?

Comment: @Mark Yes but the OP said the `contacts_item` `layout` where that `TextView` is contained isn't inflated. At least that's the way I understood it

Comment: I had a problem before where I had a custom view inside the layout that I could not access and got the same error (not inflated) and it was because I could not gain access to the textview that was part of my custom view. I had to pass it to the constructor of my custom adapter and then I was able to access it in the onclick method. Do you think that might have anything to do with this?

Comment: Yes. Your `Activity` only has access to `Views` inflated whether it be by `setContentView()` or by using `Inflater`. Unless you pass the `Context` to the other class which is what you were doing by passing it to the constructor

Comment: A `Veiw` is basically useless on its own. It needs a `ViewGroup` to be added to whether by passing a `Context` or by adding it to a `Layout`

Comment: So I guess I'm a little confused--I had the line:
`ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactItem);`
which was used to format the contents in each item in ListView, and I have to inflate it instead?

Comment: What is `contactItem`? Is that a `layout`, an `xml` file, a `Veiw`?

Comment: `contactItem` is an ID for `ListView` in the `contacts_layout` XML file.

Comment: `R.id.contactLabel` is used to get `TextLabel` so `contactLabel` needs to be a `TextView` in the layout that you inflated,  `setContentView(R.layout.contacts_layout);` Otherwise it will be `null`. If it is in there, then set a breakpoint at that line and see if `TextLabel` is null or if it is `info` that is `null`. If you post the xml with the layout contacts_layout` it may help also

Comment: Wow...I was using the wrong variable to debug in the log...go me. TextLabel IS coming out to be null. I'm gonna try inflating it though, and see how it goes.

Comment: Ok, hope it works for you. Remember inflating can be done using `inflater()` or `setContentView()` but it has to be done to use a `View` in a `Layout`. If this works then please accept so others can find it

Comment: Inflating got rid of the NPE. Now my app just crashes upon clicked text...lol.

Comment: Making progress :) If you debug and can't figure it out then feel free to post a new question with logcat and relevant code